# Updating second level embedded array in mongdb without using index?

Tags: mongodb

I am having following document in mongodb

```
 {
   "CompanyCode" : "xyz",
   "TktDetail" : [
        {
        "Type" : "ab yyy (123+4)",
         "Qty" : [{
            "1-Aug" : 48
             }, {
              "1-Sep" : 42
            }]
         }, 
         {
        "Type" : "bc xyz (123+4)",
         "Qty" : [{
        "10-Aug" : 2
              }, {
             "10-Sep" : 2
              }, {
               "11-Sep" : 2
            }]
     }]
  }
```

I want to update the `1-Aug` value in the `Qty` array which is embedded inside the `TktDetail` array.

I had tried with the following query.Its not updating

```
 db.test.update({"CompanyCode":"xyz","TktDetail.type":"ab yyy (123+4)"},{$set:{"TktDetail.$.Qty.$.1-Aug":55}});
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: not possible to do in one call until: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in a single call but here is a JIRA you can watch: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 hopefully it *might* be in for 2.5 (2.6 stable).